# Macro export to csv too many pipes

Tags: vba, excel

I have a basic macro which exports some sheets from an excel and saves them as pipe delimited files

The issue is that each worksheet has a different format and each row within a sheet may have a different number of expected fields.

At the moment the macro just exports each sheet and assumes each row has the same number of delimiters as the longest row in the worksheet.

so I end up with this

1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9

1|2||4|||||

|2|||||||

instead of this

1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9

1|2||4

|2||

What is the best way of telling the Macro how many fields to expect for each row?

Comment: Get the orginal format using Workbook.FileFormat property and save them using that.

Comment: Help us to help you... **Post your current code.**

Answer (score 0):

if each column is filled (not empty), you can do the test like not_empty(field) to know when stop the loop.